# Pulling images from a subdomain

Tags: media-library, subdomains, paths

I have created a sub-domain img.domain.com and in the database I have changed the required paths inserting the root and the url to this sub-domain. I have also changed these paths in options.php under admin setup.

All my media is uploading nicely to the new subdomain, with the year and all; folders being automatically created. In media library the image shows the link to the collect location of the image, but the image in the media library is just a blank grey box.

Am I missing something here with permissions or needing to enqueue in functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it myself..

So if anyone else has this problem.

Because the sub-domain is still under the main domain you do not have to put -

/home/hostname/subdomain.com

you only need the

/home/sub-domain.com

and everything will work..

hope this helps someone..
Richard